# LINQ to SQL Field Won't Update (Sometimes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000, datacontext

I have a MVC Web Application using the following approach:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public FooRepository fooRepository = new FooRepository();
    public BarRepository barRepository = new BarRepository();

    public ActionResult UpdateItems(int id, int range1, int range2)
    {       
        Foo foo = fooRepository.GetItem(id);
        List<Bar> bars = barRepository.GetItemsByRange(range1, range2);

        // Some validation rules here...

        DoSomeWork(foo, bars);

        // Show confirmation / error message
    }

    private void DoSomeWork(Foo foo, List<Bar> bars)
    {
        foreach(int i = 0; i < bars.Count; i++)
        {
            bars[i].Prop1 = foo.Prop1; // This field is updated
            bars[i].Owner = "someuser"; // This one too
            bars[i].Status = BarStatus.SomeStatus; // This isn't...
        }
        foo.Status = FooStatus.SomeStatus; // Ok

        // Calls DataContext.SubmitChanges()
        fooRepository.SubmitChanges();
        barRepository.SubmitChanges();      
    }
}
```

However, in some *"random"* cases (I see no pattern), one of the fields doesn't get updated, as noted in the comments.

It seems like LINQ isn't recognizing the field's update, so it gets excluded from the generated query.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something here, what could be causing it and/or how can I solve it?

**Note:** I don't get any Exception and can't verify this case in a development scenario.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience if the error is random and you can't reproduce in development than the problem is user error.

Programming would be really hard if the .net framework or the CLR just randomly decided to do things differently.

Comment: Well, I'd love to say that, but I was actually watching when this occurred. What I want to know is if there's anything particular about LINQ To SQL that I'm not aware of or missing here...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an implicit/explicit bind exclusion floating around somewhere

```
[Bind(Exclude="...,Status,...")]
```

Just guessing of course

Comment: I checked and couldn't find any of those. The update succeeds near the 97% of the cases, so I don't think it's an exclusion. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If Linq **thinks** that the Status is already BarStatus.SomeStatus, then it won't update it.

What can happen is that you find a record with the status set to this value, and then some other routine changes it, and then, if you are using your same DataContext, you will get the old value from the cached copy and hence Linq thinks that it does not need to update it.

Comment: I thought it could be something like that, but the "barRepository.GetItemsByRange" method already selects the rows where Status <> BarStatus.SomeStatus. The status is only changed in this Action and there's only one user that can update a given set of "Bar"s. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: In that case, in your loop, I would explicitly check that bars[i].Status != BarStatus.SomeStatus  and either log an error or throw an exception if it happens. This may not help find the cause of the problem, but it should at least rule out this as a possible cause.

Comment: good advice. additionally, what _is_ the type of BarStatus? We are expecting it to be of enum type, but it could just as well be any class type that has static member 'SomeStatus'

Comment: BarStatus is an enum, and I'll do what sgmoore suggested, just in case. I'll keep on searching and will post whatever I find. Thanks!